# Jquery UI Accordion not working with nested table

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to include a table inside my jQuery UI accordion.

For some reason, the section ('Download Assignments') which contains the table does not slide down/up smoothly.

Other sections of the accordion seem to work just fine.

Best way to understand the problem is to have a look - please see http://testing.xenongroupadmin.com/docman/admin/Assignments/assignments.html

Whilst on the subject, there appears to be a slight CSS glitch on the accordion as well. If you look at the bottom of the 'Download Assignments' tab, there's a small break in the border just above the next tab. This seems to have something to do with the table. If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tables don't really "do" explicit heights, once you can see 'em, you see everything. Their visibility is all or nothing.

Now a div that contains a table is a different story. Simply wrap your table in a div, let that div be the sibling to the triggering link, and you should have an easy time of it.

```
<li>
  <a href="#download">Download Assignments</a>
  <div>
    <table>
  </div>
</li>
```